# cubic spline interpolation - derivative known -

Tags: interpolation, cubics

I at the moment trying to understand how to apply the interpolation method stated above.

I have been given a start and end position, and for both position i know what their slope is. $\dot{X_a} = \alpha$ and $\dot{X_b} = \beta$  a,b being the start- and end position.

So far i see these as the required information for even being able to to solve the interpolation curve.

The note i am using states this.

[Equations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VWJFr.png)

the first and second equation makes sense. I don't get how the last two equate each other, as they could potentially (very likely) explain two different curves, and thus not equate each other. Is this an error in my note, or am i missing something here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the last equations, they are defining the cubic splines as follows:

$$S_i(t)=a_it^3+b_it^2+c_it+d_i, \quad \quad t_{i-1}\leq t \leq t_i\\
S_{i+1}(t)=a_{i+1}t^3+b_{i+1}t^2+c_{i+1}t+d_{i+1}, \quad \quad t_{i}\leq t \leq t_{i+1}$$

The second last equation states that at the end points, the first derivative of the right end point of the $i-1$'s interval (which is $t_i$) should be equal to the first derivative of the left end point of the $i$'s interval (which is also $t_i$).

The left hand side of the equation comes from $S_i(t)$. The right hand side comes from $S_{i+1}(t)$.

Same ideal applying to the second derivative gives you the last equation.

Notice that all the coefficients $a_i,...,d_i$ in each interval are to be determined. So there is no contradiction.

In each interval there are four unknown coefficients to determine. These give two equations. Combining with the equations that states the continuity on both end points will provide four equations to determine the four coefficients:

$$a_it_i^3+b_it_i^2+c_it_i+d_i=a_{i+1}t_i^3+b_{i+1}t_i^2+c_{i+1}t_i+d_{i+1}$$

Here is a picture:
[image]

The only known information is the velocity at $t_0$ and $t_N$. This is given by the first two equations. At each other end points (the intermediate $t_i$'s), you can only equate the velocity from either side.

Comment: This might just be me who overthinking this.. 
But the curve is from two points which each have an given velocity at their points.  I know that the pair  (i)  has two different velocities at their endpoint.  and at (i+1) the start endpoints has the same velocity as end endpoint of (i), but other than both start endpoint for (i) and end endpoint for (i+1) isn't the same so thereby they shouldn't equate..

Comment: @dfh: I added a picture. See if that helps.

Comment: I just re  read  it an saw that the time t is same at  both side, which make more sense..   But what makes this information more useful?

Comment: If you meant why cubic spline is useful (?), because given the data points $(t_i, y_i)$, it gives you a piecewise polynomial function which is very smooth. So you can use it to approximate other points between the intervals. I am not sure whether this is what you are asking though.

Comment: Well.. It is just stated as if it was something to notice .. big deal, that would make things easier.

Comment: @dhf: Yes it is. It gives you a function, which is not that easy to spot, that you can use to find the point, for example, somewhere between $t_0$ and $t_1$. You can even predict the velocity at that point. If you do polynomial interpolation, the result might not be that nice.